# Getting same output in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

So I was making a java class "Tile", and I added an ArrayList so I can store those tiles in it.
And i wanted to loop through the array and print out the details of each tile. I'm getting the same 
output every time. Here's the main class:

```
package com.OriginsB;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
     private static final int range = 5;
     public static ArrayList<Tile> tilearr = new ArrayList<Tile>(range);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          for(int i=1; i<range; i++){
               tilearr.add(new Tile(i, i+1));
          }
          for(int i=0; i<tilearr.size(); i++){
              System.out.println(tilearr.get(i));
          }
     }
}
```

And here's the Tile class:

```
package com.OriginsB;

public class Tile {

     private static int ID;
     private static int Pos;

     public Tile(int ident, int Position){
        Pos = Position;
        ID = ident;
     }

     @Override
     public String toString(){
        return "Tile with ID: "+ID+" with pos: "+Pos;
     }
}
```

I'm getting the same output:

```
Tile with ID: 4 with pos: 5
Tile with ID: 4 with pos: 5
Tile with ID: 4 with pos: 5
Tile with ID: 4 with pos: 5
```

Help?

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `ID` and `Pos` as `static` making them global to the class `Tile`. Remove the `static` if you want different output:

```
private int ID;
private int Pos;
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because your variables are static.

This means that if you set the value, it will be for all Tile instances.

change to

```
private int ID;
private int Pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `static` before `ID` and `Pos`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a little bit more? This is merely a comment that will help the OP to run his program but does not explain why your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Tile.java` as below

// Static modifier removed.

```
public class Tile {

    private final int ID;
    private final int Pos;

    public Tile(int ident, int Position) {
        Pos = Position;
        ID = ident;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tile with ID: " + ID + " with pos: " + Pos;
    }
```

**output**

```
Tile with ID: 1 with pos: 2
Tile with ID: 2 with pos: 3
Tile with ID: 3 with pos: 4
Tile with ID: 4 with pos: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `static` for `ID`, and `Pos`, you can use this code:

```
private int ID;
private int Pos;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Tile class fields are STATIC. Because of that their created for class not per each class instance. Working code for changed Tile class is as follows:

```
public class Tile {

    private int ID;
    private int Pos;

    public Tile(int ident, int Position){
        Pos = Position;
        ID = ident;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Tile with ID: "+ID+" with pos: "+Pos;
    }
}
```